# How to keep Quill from inserting blank paragraphs (`<p><br></p>`) before headings with a 10px top margin?

Tags: javascript, html, css, quill

## Background

CSS

```
.ql-editor h3 {
  margin-top: 10px !important;
}
```

HTML source (to be edited with Quill)

```
<div id="editor">
<h1>A Title</h1>
<p>hello</p>
<h3>A Heading</h3>
</div>
```

The JavaScript for starting Quill is:

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  theme: 'snow'
});
```

Quill.js turns it into this (I'm adding line feeds for clarity):

```
<div class="ql-editor" contenteditable="true">
<h1>A Title</h1>
<p>hello</p>
<p><br></p>
<h3>A Heading</h3>
</div>
```

## Question

Where did the `<p><br></p>` come from and how can I get rid of it?  I want the edits to look like the real thing and we use a top margin on all our headings.  A solution that stops Quill from overwriting our styles would be really nice.

## Notes

- The `.ql-editor h3` style with a `margin-top` of `10px` or greater seems critical for causing this issue.  Even with `9px` the issue goes away.
- Here is the [Quill Playground showing the issue](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RVgeBB)

## Versions

- Quill version 1.2.4
- Chrome Version 58.0.3029.81 (64-bit)
- Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)

Comment: Seems things have changed because I get the issue on h3, h2, possibly others... not on all of them, and regardless of the margin-top property, and because your quill playground is broken.

Comment: For the record, I tried out Quill, asked some stackoverflow questions, reported some bugs, then quickly switched to TinyMCE and stopped using Quill altogether.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Short version**

You need to disable the matchVisual feature:
http://quilljs.com/docs/modules/clipboard/#matchvisual

**Long version**

Quill uses the clipboard module to process it's initial content.

One of the default behaviors enabled in clipboard is a feature called *matchVisual*, which converts margins around pasted content into newlines.  The purpose is to make stuff you paste into quill look the same as its source with respect to margins.  So if I copied an h1 with a ton of margin around it from a website and pasted it in quill it would automatically put some newlines above and below to keep the same overall look.

You can see the implementation itself in the `matchSpacing` function inside clipboard.js:

https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/be41c2b0639386d52b65decc557e2cf15911ccb9/modules/clipboard.js#L297

Since initialization uses the clipboard module, this was getting applied to your text.

Here's a codepen fork illustrating the solution: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LzzYoa (the matchVisual config option was added in quill 1.3.0, and your original pen was on an older version.)

Comment: My first attempt to try this in the Quill Playground did not fix the issue.  If you include a fixed fork of my Quill Playground example showing the problem, I can accept this answer.  I'm using TinyMCE instead it's working much better for us, so not intending to spend any real time following up on this.

Comment: Apparently I don't have enough stackoverflow reputation to add another link to my answer (lol?), but here's a codepen fork illustrating the solution:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LzzYoa (the matchVisual config option was added in quill 1.3.0, and your original pen was on an older version.)

Comment: Nice!  Thank you.  Now I can see it working and you're on your way to having enough points to update your answer with the link!

Comment: The `matchVisual` option was removed in later versions. see [here](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/ee827ffb605ba491246f201d497ce0e7d9e193a0/docs/guides/upgrading-to-2-0.md#configuration).

Comment: We are having this problem, what is the solution if matchVisual is removed?

Comment: I also had this problem with quill 1.3.6 . I started to set the editor content with pure HTML out of my db when loading it. Here matchVisual kicks in. If you do via API: `Save: JSON.stringify(Editor.getContents().ops)` and `Load: Editor.setContents(json)` it should be fine !

Answer (score 4):

Just disable matchVisual option in clipboard module.

```
var quill = new Quill('.quill', {
    theme: 'snow',
    modules: {
        toolbar : [...]
        clipboard: {
            matchVisual: false
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
::ng-deep .ngx-quill-editor
  p > br
    display: none
  p:not(:last-of-type)
    margin-bottom: 1rem
```